# Exclude folder using `find` command

Tags: unix, find

I'm using the `find` command on a Mac to search for a folder called `test1`. Now `test1` folder could be present in the `.Trash` folder also. How do I exclude the `.Trash` folder from getting reported in search results or basically any folder I wish to exclude?

```
$ find $HOME  -name test1 -type d
/Users/theuser/.Trash/test1
/Users/theuser/test1 
/Users/theuser/Downloads/test1
```

I want the result to be just

```
/Users/theuser/test1
/Users/theuser/Downloads/test1
```

I used `grep`:

```
find $HOME  -name test1 -type d | grep -v '.Trash'
```

to filter out the `.Trash` result, but I'm interested in knowing if using `find` alone achieves the same results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
find $HOME -path  $HOME/.Trash -prune -o -name test1 -type d -print
```

By explicitly using `-print` you avoid the spurious printing of `.Trash`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-prune` primary:

```
find $HOME -name .Trash -prune -o -name test1 -type d
```

**Edit:**

That will include .Trash in the output. To fix that:

```
find $HOME -name .Trash -prune -o \( -name test -type d -print \)
```

Comment: Using -name will also excluded results in directories named .Trash which are not in the root of the user's home directory.

Comment: True. I went with smokingun's use of `grep -v '.Trash'` (should be `'\.Trash'`) as an indication that .Trash might appear elsewhere. I think yours is the better answer, though.