# Exclude folders with a path pattern using FIND command on Ubuntu console

Tags: ubuntu, bash, path, find, exclude

```
PROJECTS
   |___ SITE1
   |      |____files (to exclude)
   |      |____img
   |      |____js
   |
   |___ SITE2
   |      |____files (to exclude)
   |      |____img
   |      |____js
   |
   |___ SITE3
          |____files (to exclude)
          |____img
          |____js
```

Hello, I’d like to search into **SITE**x folders excluding content of ***files*** folders.

I try this but it display me permissions errors for files into ***files*** folders (so seem to not exclude them) :

```
find . ! -path "*/files/*" -type f -name 'foo'
```

It display (I’m in PROJECTS directory):

```
./SITE1/img/foo.png
./SITE1/js/foo.js
find: `./SITE1/files/201501': Permission denied
find: `./SITE1/files/201412': Permission denied
find: `./SITE1/files/201501': Permission denied
... (the two firsts matches are pretty good, but I break the execution after, it print too many indesirble matches)
```

I was inspired by this response on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/206292).

I also try the -prune option like [in this example](https://superuser.com/a/282780/326028) without finding a solution…

---

I’d like to have the equivalent of this search with egrep but for filenames

```
egrep -Rns --exclude-dir=files 'foo' *
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: We need way more information. I have no idea what you are asking. You have no direct question. Try writing again so there is a specific question you are asking.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, which is possible, an exclusion causes the "hits" to be not displayed, but does not stop the directories from being looked into.  The documentation (the --help output, the man page or something other) for the find command should indicate how find behaves.  Did you look into this documentation?

Comment: This is actually disturbingly easy to do in Windows 8... are you stuck with `find` on Linux or are you able to use Windows for this?

Comment: Try the `-prune` directive of `find`. I suggest that you search for examples (there are a few good ones right here at Super User), because the man page by itself is not very illuminating on the subject of how to use `-prune`.

Comment: @Mokubai It's disturbing how much easier this is on `*nix` than on `Windows 8`

Comment: @BroSlow On Windows 8 all you do is click inside the search box and type `-"files" -directory` and it does *exactly* what is asked without having to first open a new terminal window, `cd`'ing to the directory, then figuring out the syntax of the `find` command.  The `*nix` seems a lot like the "long" way.  But I'm not here to evangelise, I was just wanting to see if other options were available or if another method would help.

Comment: @Mokubai That would be an ok option for this example, but it's still less precise (i.e. what if you have a file called `files`?).

Answer (score 0):

Ok done !

I didn’t know how to use prune argument. This respond to my demand

```
find * -path "*/files/*" -prune -o -name 'foo' -type f -print
```

More explication [here](https://superuser.com/a/282780/326028)

---

On the other hand I should be curious if there is a syntax with the **!** (NOT) argument like in this [example on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/206292) if someone have an idea.

Comment: Yes, but the `AskUbuntu` example you linked doesn't stop `find` from continuing to traverse those directories, so you would still get the errors. Your syntax is not worse in any way, and is at worst never slower (almost always faster). Although, note that by using `*`, instead of `.`, you are likely omitting dotfiles in your top level directory